# Auto-layout and resizing views in Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, autolayout

I'm trying to make a design with auto layout for Mac OS X 10.7.

My app has a window with a fixed width/height.
What I really want to do is resize the controls in the window.
For example, I have a search field, which should expand & collapse if it's clicked.
I position a NSPathControl at the left, which should shrink if the NSSearchField expands, so they don't collapse.

Now, it works if I resize the window, but if I set the frame of the view in code, it doesn't.
Autolayout simply ignores this.

I'm simply doing `[[this animator] setFrame:newFrame];`.

Is there something I have to enable in autolayout, or do I have to set the frame differently in code?

**EDIT**

I got the constraint working by setting `self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;` in the search field.
I'm not sure if this is a great idea.

Furthermore it gives me the following log:

```
2012-12-12 19:41:30.958 Expanding Search[1428:303] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x101a0d800 h=&-- v=&-- H:[ITSearchField:0x10011bb20]-(1)-|   (Names: '|':ITPathbar:0x10190a670 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10190c520 H:[ITSearchField:0x10011bb20]-(2)-|   (Names: '|':ITPathbar:0x10190a670 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10190c520 H:[ITSearchField:0x10011bb20]-(2)-|   (Names: '|':ITPathbar:0x10190a670 )>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
2012-12-12 19:41:32.835 Expanding Search[1428:303] 74
2012-12-12 19:41:32.854 Expanding Search[1428:303] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x101a0d800 h=&-- v=&-- H:[ITSearchField:0x10011bb20]-(14.5)-|   (Names: '|':ITPathbar:0x10190a670 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10190c520 H:[ITSearchField:0x10011bb20]-(2)-|   (Names: '|':ITPathbar:0x10190a670 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10190c520 H:[ITSearchField:0x10011bb20]-(2)-|   (Names: '|':ITPathbar:0x10190a670 )>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
```

Comment: As far as I've gotten into Auto-Layout, I understand that you're not supposed to call `-setFrame:`. Can you explain how you're setting up the constraints? How is Cocoa splitting the space between the search and path controls to begin with? Are they always in the same proportion? What constraints keep them that way?

Comment: @noa I have a simple window, with a flexible height and width. So you can resize the window. Then I have a custom search field, which can change it's width, pinned at the top right side of the window. Also, I have another button, just as a test, pinned on the left side of the search field. Now, I currently set the width with `setFrame:`, and I also have to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `YES`

Comment: @noa Ok, I figured out that you can set `[[constraint animator] setConstant:newWidth];` and it works. Now I have only one question left, I'm not sure how I can actually get the width constraint. I got all the constraints using `[self constraints]` and it the first one in my example, but that of course can vary. I could make an outlet, but that doesn't seem very smart.

Comment: Yes, though it seems strange, I think an outlet is the right way to do it.

Comment: @noa thanks, I asked another question on stackoverflow, where I got this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857115/getting-an-existing-nslayoutconstraint-for-the-width/13857651#13857651

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## My solution

---

I got it, I published it on Github right [here](https://github.com/iluuu1994/ITSearchField).

I also asked another, more specific question, which was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857115/getting-an-existing-nslayoutconstraint-for-the-width).

---

The thing is that you actually shouldn't call setFrame: when you use autolayout. You should get the right constraint and alter that. It makes it a lot easier, you can simply set the width and the frame origin is handled for you automatically.