# Getting an existing NSLayoutConstraint for the width?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, autolayout

I'm trying to animate a control in Cocoa with auto layout.

Now, I can set `[[constraint animator] setConstant:newWidth];`, which works.
But how can I get the right constraint?

With `[self constraints]` you can get all the constraints, and in this case I can just select `constraints[0]`, but the order of the constraints may vary.

How can I be certain I always have the right constraint?
The constraints are set in Interface Builder. I have seen that you can add a IBOutlet to it, but it doesn't seem necessary.

---

## My solution

Thanks, it worked great. I wrote a little category.

---

### NSView+NSLayoutConstraintFilter.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface NSView (NSLayoutConstraintFilter)
- (NSLayoutConstraint *)constraintForAttribute:(NSLayoutAttribute)attribute;
- (NSArray *)constaintsForAttribute:(NSLayoutAttribute)attribute;
@end
```

---

### NSView+NSLayoutConstraintFilter.m

```
#import "NSView+NSLayoutConstraintFilter.h"

@implementation NSView (NSLayoutConstraintFilter)

- (NSArray *)constaintsForAttribute:(NSLayoutAttribute)attribute {
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstAttribute = %d", attribute];
    NSArray *filteredArray = [[self constraints] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    return filteredArray;
}

- (NSLayoutConstraint *)constraintForAttribute:(NSLayoutAttribute)attribute {
    NSArray *constraints = [self constaintsForAttribute:attribute];

    if (constraints.count) {
        return constraints[0];
    }

    return nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: why NSView? why not UIView?

Comment: @gaussblurinc It's Mac OS X

Comment: How can you be sure that the constraint is asserted on your view?  Since it's valid to add the constraint to anything up the view hierarchy it could show up in any list.  Don't you have to look up the chain, or does the constraint property on a view always include the constraints up the chain?

Comment: @tyler It very much is relevant to which view you add your constraint. A constraint will never behave the same way when added to another view (including superviews).

Comment: @NSAddict It's possible that we're misunderstanding each other, but if not then I disagree. I have view's X and Y, Y is a subview of X.  Create a constraint that equates X and Y's centerX attributes. I can add the constraint to X since it's a super of Y.  I could alternatively add it to X's superview and get the same result.  The Apple docs state that you SHOULD add the constraint to the closest common ancestor, but you aren't required to: "The view that holds the constraint must be an ancestor of the views the constraint involves, and should(!) usually(!) be the closest common ancestor."

Comment: @tyler Well this example is not a solution to all problems. You should know your applications architecture and use it where it makes sense. It's just important that the constraint is always on the same view, no matter which one it is.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Every contraint has an attribute `[constraint firstAttribute]`
It returns an enum NSLayoutAttribute

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, NSLayoutAttribute) {
    NSLayoutAttributeLeft = 1,
    NSLayoutAttributeRight,
    NSLayoutAttributeTop,
    NSLayoutAttributeBottom,
    NSLayoutAttributeLeading,
    NSLayoutAttributeTrailing,
    NSLayoutAttributeWidth,
    NSLayoutAttributeHeight,
    NSLayoutAttributeCenterX,
    NSLayoutAttributeCenterY,
    NSLayoutAttributeBaseline,

    NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute = 0
};
```

so you can check NSLayoutAttributeWidth for width.

Sample code:

```
NSArray constraints = [self constraints];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstAttribute = %d", NSLayoutAttributeWidth];
NSArray *filteredArray = [constraints filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
if(filteredArray.count == 0){
      return nil;
}
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint =  [constraints objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Great answer, worked like a charm, I wrote a category, take a look.

Comment: if(filteredArray.count == 0){
      return nil;
}
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint =  [constraints objectAtIndex:0]; this can be avoided by using NSLayoutConstraint *constraint =  [constraints lastIndex];

Answer (score 6):

Here is the swift 3 version tested on Xcode 8.2.1 and macOS 10.12.2.

The code shows how to get a button's width and height constraints, but you could filter whatever you want from `NSLayoutAttribute` enum.

```
let cons = signInButton.constraints.filter {
    $0.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.width || $0.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.height /// or other from `NSLayoutAttribute`
}
// do something with the constraints array, e.g.
NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(cons)
```

Comment: When I use this, some constraints are missing

Answer (score 0):

#### I wrote a reusable extension: (Swift 4.1)

```
/**
 * Utils when working with constraints
 */
extension NSLayoutConstraint{
    /**
     * Returns all constraints of kinds
     * EXAMPLE: NSLayoutConstraint.ofKind(rect.immediateConstraints, kinds: [.width,.height]) //width, height
     */
    static func ofKind(_ constraints:[NSLayoutConstraint],kinds:[NSLayoutAttribute]) -> [NSLayoutConstraint]{
        return kinds.map { kind in
            return constraints.filter { constraint in
                return constraint.firstAttribute == kind
            }
        }.flatMap({$0})//flattens 2d array to 1d array
    }
}
```